# Signeds3upload cannot load SVF, but it can load SVF2

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

When I upload the a model using the [older method of uploading to an OSS bucket](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-PUT/), the model works perfectly with SVF. However, when utilizing the [direct-to-S3 approach](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3upload-GET/), I encountered difficulties in loading SVF of the same model.

In second case, it was translating model to SVF format, on checking manifest, model translation status was successful and I was able to fetch the metadata successfully but it failed to load with SVF and shows error as shown in screenshot.

On deleting the manifest for SVF and re-translating it using SVF2, it worked as expected.

1. How come I didn’t face this issue when I was using older method of uploading to an OSS?
2. Does autodesk forge planning on deprecating SVF recommend using SVF2 format onwards?
3. I have a few old models translated to SVF form which are working fine, shall I re-translating them to SVF2?

(Note: I’m using Autodesk forge viewer v=v7.55. I have attached the model link and a screenshot of the error for reference.)

[Link to model](https://grabcad.com/library/epoxy-granite-vertical-cnc-mill-1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your questions in the order you asked:

1. **How come I didn’t face this issue when I was using older method of uploading to an OSS?**

The old OSS upload endpoint was used with SVF for a very long time hence why it worked effectively with SVF.
The old OSS upload endpoint was deprecated at the end of 2022.

The new Direct-to-S3 approach uses Amazon S3 storage. I should mention that the Direct-to-S3 endpoint also works fine with SVF. This is the endpoint all APS users should use when uploading their models to OSS buckets.
You can learn more about the migration to Direct-to-S3 in this blog post: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-oss-object-storage-service-migrating-direct-s3-approach

2. **Does autodesk forge planning on deprecating SVF recommend using SVF2 format onwards?**

As far as am aware, there are no plans to deprecate the SVF format. SVF is still widely used by developers when viewing their models on the Viewer.

Whether you want to use SVF or SVF2 will depend entirely on the needs of your project.

You can learn more about the differences between SVF and SVF2 formats by going through the following blogs:

https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-svf2-enhancements-part-1-viewer

https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-svf2-enhancements-part-2-metadata

https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/update-svf2-ga-new-streaming-web-format-forge-viewer-now-production-ready

3. **I have a few old models translated to SVF form which are working fine, shall I re-translating them to SVF2?**

As I mentioned, SVF is still widely used by APS developers and is also supported by Autodesk.

You don't have to translate all your models to SVF2 if you don't need all your model files to be in SVF2 format. You can still use the SVF format. Besides, you mentioned that your SVF models are still working fine so I'd suggest you keep them that way.